# Is asking about "Anime Crossovers" off-topic here?

Tags: discussion

I've been asking in beta about anime crossovers 'cause I'm really interested about it. But they always vote for my question to be closed. Is topic about anime crossovers too off-topic to ask here? Just making sure so that my effort of asking won't be forsaken. Thanks a lot.

Comment: It sounds a bit like a list-type question. The recipe of not-constructive.

Comment: I'll give you an example of what I asked, "What particular anime first showcased crossover?" Is this not-constructive?

Comment: Hence "a bit like". So it's not completely in that category. But it's still leaning slightly in that direction.

Comment: How come? I think it's like asking "What was the first anime?" and just an answer of "Astroboy". Is that under a list-type of question?

Comment: To be very nitpicky, it was because "Anime(s)" was plural in the question. That immediately raised the "not-constructive" flag when I first read it. But now that I read it again, it isn't that bad.

Comment: I used "Anime(s)" because I'm not sure if the answer involves only one or two or more animes. So, can I conclude that "anime crossovers" topic is allowed in here, and that it only depends on how the user asked the question?

Comment: "and that it only depends on how the user asked the question?" - Unfortunately, that actually is indeed the case. Numerous times on meta.SO I see people saying that X question needs to be phrased better. Because how the question is asked will solicit different types of answers. If it is phrased improperly, it could solicit the type that will ultimately turn the question into a non-constructive trap.

Comment: All a while I thought that "anime crossovers" is off-topic here. Since they've been voting to close my questions about it. Thanks.

Comment: Should I pull the comments into an answer?

Comment: @mysticial, can you then answer my question here, not as comment but as an answer? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pulling the comments into here:

When I first read the title:

> What particular anime(s) first showcased crossovers?

It immediately struck me as being the typical non-constructive question. Why? Because it sounds like it is asking for a list.

At the very core, the question is fairly legit. There can only be *one* Anime that had the *first* crossover. So it has an objective answer to it. I won't go into whether or not that answer is obtainable as SingerOfTheFall's answer covers that quite well.

However, the trick to these borderline questions is that they need to be phrased correctly.
Depending on a how a question is phrased, it can lead to different types of answers. Phrasing it incorrectly could send the question into a downward spiral towards non-constructive land.

As your current title stands, the plural on "anime(s)" could possibly bait many answers from different people who have opinions on what is "among the first". But phrasing it as:

> "What Anime first showcased crossovers?"

would tip it back towards that constructive direction. To make the question more constructive, you can request that all answers have authoritative evidence that they are the first. ([Skeptics](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/) has a policy of requiring references to avoid this speculation trap.)

But as SingerOfTheFall mentions, it may be difficult in this case. But that's a separate issue.

Comment: As I mentioned a while ago, "Anime(s)" was used because the answer can be hypothetically be like this, "The first anime that showcased crossovers is the Anime1 that involved the appearance of Character2 from Anime2". It was just use because of the uncertainty of the probable answer.

Comment: Then we're stuck in a hole aren't we? If the only way to make the question possible is to phrase non-constructively then that's gonna be an issue. Don't get me wrong though. Whether or not the question can be answered is a completely separate issue from whether it is constructive.

Comment: Not really: "Which pair/group of animes got crossed over first", or "when did the first crossover between animes occur" would be unambiguous about the count. It's a matter of wording and good will in reading. And even if not, I see no reason why a list of first few crossovers would be wrong - it's not like the list is arbitrarily long and would elicit undue, unwelcome discussion if the fifth is one of the first or isn't.

Answer (score 4):

It's not really a list question. To me it's hard but reasonably narrow. A list question is "How many anime have a prick as a main character?" (lol just an example).

When answers start to go over 10, then you must worry.

In any case, it depends. As a moderator I've left open questions that could have been Not constructive but that only received one answer. So my opinion is: keep an eye on such questions, if too many answers start to come in, then vote to close.

Answer (score 1):

Your question is, and is not a list question at the same time.

On one hand, it indeed needs a short answer containing only the anime name. However, there is one problem: we can't know everything.

What does that mean in your context? That means that the question will become a list question eventually. Some person might think "Hey ok, Anime AAA was the first one, since it was released in 1990", and post it as an answer. Then another person comes and thinks "Hey, but there was also Anime BBB which appeared a year earlier!", and posts *this* as his own answer. Then another person comes... and so on and so forth. So eventually it will be a list-competition question with people trying to remember earlier and earlier examples of crossovers.

Probably if you rephrase the question to somehow avoid such a situation, it will be gladly reopened.

Comment: Thanks. But what you mentioned as an example, should that be a problem? I mean, you want to know the "first", so if someone knows the "earliest", then much better. Or should it be a problem? I thought that by "list-type", you mean like asking "Enumerate animes that starts with letter 'A'" type of question.

Comment: @xjshiya, I don't know if it is _that much_ of a problem, or if this is enough to close it. I've just seen that before, so I decided to let you know ;)