# Should anime/manga influence questions be allowed?

Tags: discussion

I just saw [Has the "It's over 9000!" meme spread back to Japan?](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/752/has-the-its-over-9000-meme-spread-back-to-japan) and was trying to figure out if this is on-topic. It is about anime but only in the sense that it is asking about anime's influence in Japan.

Should questions about anime/mange memes or anime/manga's influence in different countries be allowed?

Answer (score 5):

I don't see why not. The linked question is most definitely answerable (probably better than my answer), and it's related to anime. If we can ask about the cultural influence of other aspects of culture on anime (as in [this question](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/278/is-no-face-from-spirited-away-based-on-any-traditional-japanese-legends)), then we should also be allowed to ask about the cultural influence of anime on other aspects of culture. I can think of a number of interesting questions like this, which I don't see any reason to restrict.

I'd also like to second the opinion of [Creating too many rules](https://anime.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/249/creating-too-many-rules), that we shouldn't create more rules or ban things unless there's a clear reason to do so, because it makes our site less user-friendly. In this case, I don't see any such reason.

Answer (score 3):

For this specific question, I don't think it should be allowed. The focus of the question is more on meme/Internet culture than anime itself.

If somebody were to ask "What is the it's over 9000 meme from?" that might be OK depending on how we feel about identification questions. But, as the question is, it's not really asking about anime. It's just asking about a meme that happened to be from anime.

Sorry, I don't have much more to add because I see it as something rather clear cut. If anybody else who agrees with me has more to add, feel free to edit as I've made this answer a community wiki.